# getElementById not finding element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery to count dynamically generated list items and in the array - getting the initial values of objects like:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("<div></div>").load("/Stats/Contents #stats", function () {
         statcount = $(".list-group-item", this).length;
         for (var j = 0; j < statcount; j++) {
             statList.push(stat);
         }
         for (var i = 0; i < statcount; i++) {
             statList[i].statId = document.getElementById("statId-" + (i + 1)  ).value;
             statList[i].productDescription = document.getElementById("productType-" + 
                 (i + 1)).value;
             statList[i].lastMeasuredInventoryAmount = document.getElementById
             ("statLastMeasureAmount-" + (i + 1)).value;
         }
    )}
)}
```

I got 2 issues here: 
1) When I am using 
    `$('').load("/Stats/Contents #stats", function () {`
as above, it doesn't find the element unless browser is refreshed.

2) So I changed it to -
    `$('').on("load","/Stats/Contents #stats", function () {`
    
After changing, issue #1 is fixed. However - now it doesn't count using the statement inside the function:
    **statcount = $(".list-group-item", this).length;**

Any ideas how to make both work?
Thanks

Comment: If you're using jQuery why are you using `getElementById()`?

Comment: knowing getElementById as a easy thing to use, would that make a difference?

Comment: No, just curious. I guess I consider jQuery to be pretty convenient generally, if a little unfashionable nowadays.

Comment: `.on('load'` is different than `.load('url'`, the first one is an event handler, like the `.load(function(){})` version. The second one is the load external resource method.

Comment: More importantly, what is `statList`? And `statCount`? Where are they declared?

Comment: Also `$("<div></div>").load` is going to load your content in an element that is not in the DOM, so a `document.getElementById` wouldn't be able to grab any of the elements as they are not in `document`

Comment: @PatrickEvans - I found <code>.on('load'</code>  as a solution to fixing the not finding the element by id issue, so tried to use it. So what would be the right way to do it so it parses through the dynamic list and counts?

Comment: @Pointy - statList is a global object array, statCount a global number to count dynamically generated html elements

Comment: Load the actual content into the `document` before using getElementById, or use `this` and with a jQuery object, eg `$('#statId...',this)`

Comment: Well understand that `.load()` is an **asynchronous** operation. The `.load()` function returns immediately, but that callback function won't be invoked until the HTTP request completes.

Comment: the question is unclear and the provided the snippet is missing declarations.  It would be nice to know the structure of the return of `/Stats/Contents`.  What are you expecting by providing a bookmark to that URL?  Is the result HTML/JSON/XML?

Comment: @PatrickEvans - using object, eg $('#statId...',this) inside <code>$("<div></div>").load </code> like before improved it so I don't get the issue of needing to refresh the browser because it wont recognize the id first time and get into script error. I don't get the script error - How ever, is there a way to count the dynamic elements inside some other load because there is something (without error) that causes the navigation to collapse that was happening with script error.

Comment: Thanks all...!!!